# Win 10 won't boot without SD card inserted

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, windows-10, sd-card

My girlfriend installed windows 10 without any issues aside from the fact that her PC would no longer read any SD card inserted in the slot.  (We had just returned from a trip to Italy and were desperate to try to post our pics.)  I simply rebooted the PC with the SD card inserted and upon bootup, the card was visible in the file manager and all seemed well.  However, whenever she tries to boot the PC without the SD card inserted, the system locks up.  It has to be that specific SD card as well.  Trying other cards will cause the system to seize.  I've already checked the boot order and the system is set to book from the hard drive first and the hard drive has not been disabled as I've read some other people with similar issues have found the problem to be.  If I remove the card without using the "safe remove" option, the system will lock up as well, but if I use the "safe remove" option, I can remove the card and continue to work, but rebooting causes the same lockup when the card is not there.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use SD cards to boost the speed of the computer.  You might have told Windows 10 to use this device to speed up your computer especially if it is looking for that exact SD card.

With the SD card inserted and available, call up the properties menu and look for a Readyboost tab.  Click on it and select Do Not Use.

Comment: I checked the properties of the SD card and Readyboost is alread set to, "Do Not Use".